# Typescript: pass inferred type through React's useCallback

Tags: javascript, typescript

Example:

```
function useCallback(fn) {
  return fn;
}

type ApiData = {
  '/user': { user: any },
  '/post': { post: any },
};

function useApi<Path extends keyof ApiData>(
  path: Path,
  opts: {
    cb?: (data: ApiData[Path]) => void,
  },
) {}

useApi('/user', { cb: ({ user }) => null }); // ok
useApi('/user', { cb: ({ post }) => null }); // Property 'post' does not exist on type '{ user: any; }'
useApi('/user', { cb: useCallback(({ user }) => null) }); // ok
useApi('/user', { cb: useCallback(({ post }) => null) }); // should have error
```

TS Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABCAzgUwMIEMA2OBGWEA1gBTBgCUiA3gFCKIBOaUITSFA3HQL510oATwAOaRAEERMACJYoWRAF5aDRAHIA9KjRN1ALlrJ0TQ1jBDEvADRqtIuCigGjDp2YtXbvHnVCRYBGM0KRgAHgAFeQALRDQADyg0MAATFERiNCE4YElpOQUAPlI1ERjDKKho20Y4ESgUQ3pGRgh8AH5DUhT5LENQgqwAbUrogF1qJULEADc4GBSarzpqGn46HVDSLR09ayM2rppgpitJ6bAQPDOuRE1NRDhiDfQtnZN1fePDxFJjtygZ2UFyuOBudweESYdV0wg0APUiBScDQ6TAcEBCRgTkeSGEYg0x12HiEt146heIWk220Hy+iB+OmweEIJFIfxOQKmiEueGovEot3uj2em2p710nwO+EMTNwBCIZA5AK5IL54OFKGicCuKUQ0SwM3EumhTAEQA

In this example, without `useCallback`, TS was able to automatically determine the type of the callback's argument's type. However, with `useCallback`, it loses that ability.

Interestingly, if I make the `cb` property required, then TS is able to infer the type of the argument:

```
function useApi<Path extends keyof ApiData>(
  path: Path,
  opts: {
    cb: (data: ApiData[Path]) => void, // <- removed the "?"
  },
) {}

useApi('/user', { cb: useCallback(({ post }) => null) }); // Property 'post' does not exist on type '{ user: any; }'
```

How can I make TS infer the argument of the callback?

Comment: Having the exact same problem. Not sure why this was downvoted. Somehow type inference stops working when the parameter is optional.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter with `?` optional operator

Typescript parser is properly inferring what the types are.

Since you specified first parameter of useApi function as `'/user'`, it wouldn't work.

Change it to,

```
useApi('/post', { cb: useCallback(({ post }) => null) });
```

It would work.

Comment: OP expects the error in this case, see _// should have error_ comment. The error is not shown because callback type is widened